# How do I plot a daily value in Cloudwatch Metrics?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I am expecting to see build time durations plotted as time series line chart. Idea is to show a dip in duration on 2023-12-04, but instead Cloudwatch shows nothing:

[image: Cloudwatch Graph]

What am I missing please? This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ts-node

import {
  CloudWatchClient,
  PutMetricDataCommand,
} from '@aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch';

export const client = new CloudWatchClient({ region: "eu-west-2" });

interface buildTime {
  duration: number;
  date: Date;
}
const buildTimes: buildTime[] = [
  { duration: 30000, date: new Date("2023-12-01") },
  { duration: 30000, date: new Date("2023-12-02") },
  { duration: 30000, date: new Date("2023-12-03") },
  { duration: 10000, date: new Date("2023-12-04") },
  { duration: 30000, date: new Date("2023-12-05") },
  { duration: 30000, date: new Date("2023-12-06") },
]

async function sendMetrics(data: buildTime[]) {

  const command = new PutMetricDataCommand({
    MetricData: data.map((entry) => ({
      MetricName: 'buildTime',
      Timestamp: entry.date,
      Unit: 'Milliseconds',
      Value: entry.duration,
    })),
    Namespace: 'Test',
  });

  try {
    return await client.send(command);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

sendMetrics(buildTimes).then(() => console.log('Done'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I logged in the next day to find the expected chart!

[image: visualisation of build time]

Lesson learned: Be patient?